# How to create multiple txt files with incrementing numbers and writing in them using batch files (.bat)

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I want to create multiple txt files with incrementing numbers with batch; here's my example

```
@echo off
for /l %i in (1,1,13) do
  @echo bla bla bla > "%i.txt"   
  @echo bla bla blo > "%i.txt"   
  @echo bli bli bla > "%i.txt"   
  @echo blom blom blom > "%i.txt"
```

Help me, please.

Comment: Please read [For - Loop through a range of numbers - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html) - you need parentheses when using miltiple command in a for loop.

Comment: Please read [Command Redirection, Pipes - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) - You are overwriting the file each time you echo to it.

Comment: Please read [For - Looping commands - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) - You need to use `%%` inside a batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will create files `1.txt` through to `13.txt` in the current working directory.
Each file will contain the 4 lines of Text specified.

```bat
@echo off
for /l %%a in (1,1,13) do (
   >>%%a.txt echo bla bla bla
   >>%%a.txt echo bla bla blog
   >>%%a.txt echo bla bla bla
   >>%%a.txt echo blom blom blom
)
```

Notes:
When you use `@echo off` it hides command execution output from that point onwards in the script. This means you do not need to add `@` before any commands after this point.

Using `echo blah blah > %%A.txt` will work, however you will actually end up with `blah blah{space}` (A space on the end of line) written to the file.
Instead, use `>>%%a.txt echo blah blah` will result in just `blah blah`

---

**EDIT:**

Added this option based on comments by OP re using body text from file.

```bat
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type "C:\Test Folder\MyList.txt"') do (
    set /a count+=1
    >!count!.txt echo %%a
)
endlocal
exit /B
```

This will read the lines one by one from `C:\Test Folder\MyList.txt`, and for each line it will add `1` to the variable called `count`.

Next it will create a file named as the current line number (Eg. `1.txt` `2.txt`) and it place into that file the current line it has read from the `MyList.txt` file.

So if you had a the following lines in the `MyList.txt` file...

```bat
Hey i'm first
Hi i'm second
Third line
```

You would end up with...

`1.txt` containing the line `Hey i'm first`

`2.txt` containing the line `Hi i'm second`

`3.txt` containing the line `Third line`

Comment: it actually creates the txt files but in each file it writes all the text.

Comment: it actually creates the txt files but in each file it writes all the text.
What I want is, in 1.txt there is only "bla bla"  and in 2.txt there is only "blo blo" and so on.
I hope you understand me.

Comment: Will there only be 1 line in each file? If it is only 13 files...wouldn't it be easy to just manually create each.

Comment: actually I have another one that contains 106. I forgot it.

Comment: How are the comments/lines stored? Do you have them all on individual lines in the one text file?

Comment: Yes.­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: @Rachid i've edited my answer to include an option based on your extra information

Comment: Ooooh!! thank you so so much @Durry42, you saved my life. I've lost hope for doing this thing.
Thank you again.

Comment: @Rachid you're welcome. Please remember to mark if this answer has helped.

Answer (score 0):

A much more simplified answer:

```
@echo off

::Create variable that stores newline, can be used as %NL%
( set LF=^
%= EMPTY =%
)
set "NL=^^^%LF%%LF%^%LF%%LF%"

for /L %%? in (1,1,13) do echo bla bla bla%NL%bla bla blog%NL%bli bli bla%NL%blom blom blom>%%?.txt
```

or, without `DELAYEDEXPANSION` enabled:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

::Create variable that stores newline, can be used as !LF!
( set LF=^
%= EMPTY =%
)

for /L %%? in (1,1,13) do echo bla bla bla!LF!bla bla blog!LF!bli bli bla!LF!blom blom blom>%%?.txt
```

Make sure to also check out:

- SS64's [documentation](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) about `FOR`
- How the [newline hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379619/explain-how-windows-batch-newline-variable-hack-works) works